# Ip Tunneling Driver

Tags: networking

I am trying to use a AppGate client on my Ubuntu 12.04.
some AppGate client services need IP Tunneling driver to be installed and running on the system in order to work.
I have  downloaded IP Tunneling driver for Linux but do not know how start it.
Does anybody know how to run it?
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue.
I found a  package (provided by appgate website )that contains script files and a ReadMe file describing the steps to do that. 
I followed the instruction from the readme file and it worked.